# Copy tables and views from Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

Hi I need to copy tables and views from one Athena instance to another (I'm not using Glue). How to do this via AWS Console or via boto3/pyathena api without loosing any data? Cant find anything in documentation :(

Answer (score 1):

Athena tables are built on top of files stored on S3. If you need the data, you will have to export the data.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply - yes I know. But current instance contains custom tables and views describing relationships between different parts of data.